# Is it possible to use softmax for anomaly detection?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, anomaly-detection, cross-entropy

Suppose we have a model for classification.

Normally the head of the model is a `softmax` over all the label/categories. Is it a good idea (that is being used in practice) to use the `softmax` values for anomaly detection? That is, if `argmax(softmax(labels)` isn't significant enough we can assume it's an anomaly in the data.

A more advanced thing we can do is checking the cross-entropy or KL divergence between the `softmax` values and a one-hot vector that has `1` in the `argmax` place.

Is it something people do in practice?

Comment: How exactly would you like to use the predictions for anomaly detection? What is your model? What is your data?

Comment: The data/model could be whatever. My idea is: We train a model on a classified data. Given a new input we can check the softmax values. If there's no significant result it *could* mean that the input is some sort of an anomaly. So yes, to answer your question my idea is to use the predictions for anomaly detection.

Comment: Specifically, my data is text (description) and the target is an item

Answer (score 2):

Let's use a trivial example, you have a two-class classifier that categorizes images into dogs and cats. It returns probabilities for two columns $(p_1, p_2)$ where $p_2 = 1 - p_1$, so we can ignore second column. If $p_1$ is high, it classifies an image as a dog, when it is low, hence $p_2$ is high, it classifies image as a cat. As you can see, high and low probabilities do not tell us much about the image being anomalous. If the predicted probability is in the middle between 0 and 1, the model is not sure about the prediction. In such sense, you could set up some threshold over the probabilities to find the images that the model considers as atypical examples of dogs and cats. However if you trained and tuned the model for classification, keep in mind that it would have a pretty narrow sense of what is atypical: the images that are hard to classify. Those may, or may not be anomalies, though might be worth a closer look when analyzing models performance.